# Vuetify- How to make a link in the textarea clickable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hyperlink, vuetify.js, textarea

I have a simple v-textarea

```
<v-textarea v-model="text"/></v-textarea>
```

Is there a way to detect that a link has been inserted and make it change color and be clickable?

Such as this https://stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make clickable links inside textareas (v-textarea is just a wrapper around a native one). They are for plain text only.

As a possible workaround you can you can make a div, copy formatted content from the textarea to this div with the appropriate wrapping of links into the  tags and then switch the textarea and div on blur event or maybe a custom switcher